# Cant search in XML file with xcode

Tags: ios, xml, searchbar

I make parsing with XML file. I can not search the data I get with XML. I create array and can search in this objects. How can I do now?

I have no problem didload active in self.array but I need to use eksperlist. Iam not searching where I look the data with in ekperlist.

I need help for search :(

H File;

```
//
//  eksperlerimiz.h
//  eksperlerimiz
//
//  Created by Apple on 05/03/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Apple. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "eksper.h"
@interface eksperlerimiz : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate,NSXMLParserDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate>
{
    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableArray *eksperlistesi;
    Eksper *eksper;
    NSString *currentElement;

    __weak IBOutlet UITableView *searchBar;
    IBOutlet UITableView *table;
}

@end
```

M File;

```
//
//  eksperlerimiz.m
//  eksperlerimiz
//
//  Created by Apple on 05/03/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Apple. All rights reserved.
//

#import "eksperlerimiz.h"

@interface eksperlerimiz ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *array;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *searchResults;

@end

@implementation eksperlerimiz
#pragma Table View Methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [self.searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [self.array count];
    }



        //return [self.array count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    static NSString *cellID = @"mycell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

     if (cell == nil)
     {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
     }
     if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
     cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     } else {
     cell.textLabel.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     }

    return cell;


/*
    Eksper *temp = [eksperlistesi objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mycell"];
    NSString *str =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",temp.sehir];
    NSString *str2 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",temp.banka];
    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel *detailtitleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    titleLabel.text = str2;
    detailtitleLabel.text = str;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;
*/
}



-(void)getXMLData
{
    NSString *strURL = @"http://www.serkanuyanik.com/eksperlerimiz.xml";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSLog([[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    eksperlistesi = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    currentElement = elementName;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"record"])
        eksper = [[Eksper alloc] init];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"banka"])
        [eksper.banka appendString:[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""]];
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"sehir"])
        [eksper.sehir appendString:[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""]];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"record"])
    {
        [eksperlistesi addObject:eksper];
    }

}

-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
        [table reloadData];

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getXMLData) withObject:nil];
//    self.array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple", @"Samsung", @"HTC", @"LG", @"Moto", nil];

    self.searchResults = [[NSArray alloc] init];
//    self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//    self.array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:eksperlistesi];

      self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:eksperlistesi];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma Search Methods

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", searchText];
    //    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contains[c] %@", searchText];
    self.searchResults = [self.array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: What do you mean "can't search" ?

Comment: I have changed. Thank you.

Comment: What is eksperlistesi?  Does getXMLData set eksperlistesi?  What exactly is failing and where?  What errors do you get?  Do some debugging.  Put NSLogs to show variable values and see method calls and the order of their execution.

Comment: I changed some parts

Answer (score 0):

I have changed some parts. I dont see XML file in table view.

```
//
//  eksperlerimiz.m
//  eksperlerimiz
//
//  Created by Apple on 05/03/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Apple. All rights reserved.
//

#import "eksperlerimiz.h"

@interface eksperlerimiz ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *eksperlerimiz;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *searchResults;

@end

@implementation eksperlerimiz
#pragma Table View Methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [self.searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [self.eksperlerimiz count];
    }



        //return [self.array count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    static NSString *cellID = @"mycell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

     if (cell == nil)
     {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
     }
     if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
     cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     } else {
     cell.textLabel.text = [self.eksperlerimiz objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     }

    return cell;


/*
    Eksper *temp = [eksperlistesi objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mycell"];
    NSString *str =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",temp.sehir];
    NSString *str2 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",temp.banka];
    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel *detailtitleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    titleLabel.text = str2;
    detailtitleLabel.text = str;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;
*/
}



-(void)getXMLData
{
    NSString *strURL = @"http://www.serkanuyanik.com/eksperlerimiz.xml";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSLog([[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    eksperlistesi = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    currentElement = elementName;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"record"])
        eksper = [[Eksper alloc] init];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"banka"])
        [eksper.banka appendString:[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""]];
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"sehir"])
        [eksper.sehir appendString:[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""]];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"record"])
    {
        [eksperlistesi addObject:eksper];
    }

}

-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
        [table reloadData];

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getXMLData) withObject:nil];

    self.searchResults = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    self.eksperlerimiz = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma Search Methods

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", searchText];
    //    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contains[c] %@", searchText];
    self.searchResults = [self.eksperlerimiz filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

@end
```